# DBpedia SPARQL filter does not apply to all results

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

A `FILTER NOT EXISTS` allows some results through when combined with `OPTIONAL` triples.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE 
{
  {
    ?en rdfs:label "N'Djamena"@en .
    BIND("N'Djamena" AS ?name) .
  }
  UNION {
    ?en rdfs:label "Port Vila"@en .
    BIND("Port Vila" AS ?name) .
  }
  UNION {
    ?en rdfs:label "Atafu"@en .
    BIND("Atafu" AS ?name) .
  }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?en rdf:type skos:Concept } .
  OPTIONAL { ?en owl:sameAs ?es . FILTER regex(?es, "es.dbpedia") .  }
  OPTIONAL { ?en owl:sameAs ?pt . FILTER regex(?pt, "pt.dbpedia") .  }
} 
LIMIT 100
```

This query gets the three places as expected, but it also pulls back "Category:Atafu", which should be filtered out by virtue of having "rdf:type skos:Concept".

When used without the `OPTIONAL` lines, I get the three places expected. When used with those clauses non-optionally, I get only two of the countries, because Atafu doesn't have a page in Portuguese.

I can also move the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` statement into each of the UNION'd country blocks, but that seems to hurt the server's response time.

Why does the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` clause filter out "Category:N'Djamena" and `Category:Port_Vila` but not "Category:Atafu" when followed by `OPTIONAL`?

Comment: What SPARQL engine are you using?  (Seems to work for Jena ARQ.)  Have you looked into VALUES in SPARQL?  That fits your use of UNION better.

Comment: Oh, did you see the difference between <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Atafu> and <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Atafu>?  The latter is a member of skos:Concept and is indeed filtered out by the query.  The former is a valid result.

Comment: I'm using DBpedia's Virtuoso editor. http://dbpedia.org/sparql I just play around with my query there, then submit an HTTP request to that endpoint from my web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really have no idea why your query doesn't work.  I'd have to chalk it up to some weird Virtuoso thing.  There's definitely something strange going on.  For instance, if you remove the **bind** for the last name, you'll get the resources you're expecting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE 
{
  {
    ?en rdfs:label "N'Djamena"@en .
    BIND("N'Djamena" AS ?name) .
  }
  UNION {
    ?en rdfs:label "Port Vila"@en .
    BIND("Port Vila" AS ?name) .
  } 
  UNION {
    ?en rdfs:label "Atafu"@en .
  }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?en rdf:type skos:Concept }
  OPTIONAL { ?en owl:sameAs ?es . FILTER regex(?es, "es.dbpedia") }
  OPTIONAL { ?en owl:sameAs ?pt . FILTER regex(?pt, "pt.dbpedia") .  }
} 
LIMIT 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fen%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22N%27Djamena%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%28%22N%27Djamena%22%20AS%20%3Fname%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fen%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Port%20Vila%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%28%22Port%20Vila%22%20AS%20%3Fname%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20UNION%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fen%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Atafu%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fen%20rdf%3Atype%20skos%3AConcept%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fen%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fes%20.%20FILTER%20regex%28%3Fes%2C%20%22es.dbpedia%22%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fen%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fpt%20.%20FILTER%20regex%28%3Fpt%2C%20%22pt.dbpedia%22%29%20.%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

It's really pretty weird.  Here's a modified version of your query that gets the results you're looking for.  It uses **values** instead of **union**, which makes the query simpler.  It should be logically equivalent, though, so I'm not sure why it makes a difference.

```
select distinct * where {
  values ?label { "N'Djamena"@en "Port Vila"@en "Atafu"@en }
  ?en rdfs:label ?label .
  optional { ?en owl:sameAs ?pt . filter regex(?pt, "pt.dbpedia") }
  optional { ?en owl:sameAs ?es . filter regex(?es, "es.dbpedia") }
  filter not exists { ?en a skos:Concept }
  bind(str(?label) as ?name)
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Flabel%20%7B%20%22N%27Djamena%22%40en%20%22Port%20Vila%22%40en%20%22Atafu%22%40en%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fen%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fen%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fpt%20.%20filter%20regex%28%3Fpt%2C%20%22pt.dbpedia%22%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fen%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fes%20.%20filter%20regex%28%3Fes%2C%20%22es.dbpedia%22%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%20%3Fen%20a%20skos%3AConcept%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20bind%28str%28%3Flabel%29%20as%20%3Fname%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I'd actually clean up the string matching though, since regular expressions are probably more power than you need here.  You just want to check whether the value starts with a given substring:

```sql
select ?en ?label (str(?label) as ?name) ?es ?pt where {
  values ?label { "N'Djamena"@en "Port Vila"@en "Atafu"@en }
  ?en rdfs:label ?label .
  optional { ?en owl:sameAs ?pt . filter strstarts(str(?pt), "http://pt.dbpedia") }
  optional { ?en owl:sameAs ?es . filter strstarts(str(?es), "http://es.dbpedia") }
  filter not exists { ?en a skos:Concept }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fen%20%3Flabel%20%28str%28%3Flabel%29%20as%20%3Fname%29%20%3Fes%20%3Fpt%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Flabel%20%7B%20%22N%27Djamena%22%40en%20%22Port%20Vila%22%40en%20%22Atafu%22%40en%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fen%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fen%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fpt%20.%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fpt%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fpt.dbpedia%22%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fen%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fes%20.%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fes%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia%22%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%20%3Fen%20a%20skos%3AConcept%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: That's a fantastic refactoring of my original query; I didn't even know you could use bind and values together that way. The ruby dev will be happy to see these results!

Comment: And just for the record, thank you for proving it wasn't just me. I appreciate that almost as much as the educational answer. :-)