# SPARQL not returning owl:sameAs properties that exist in DBpedia

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sparql, dbpedia

I'm having some success from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440591/dbpedia-sparql-filter-does-not-apply-to-all-results), but grabbing results for other DBpedia languages is failing for some (but not all) entries.

For example,

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  VALUES ?label {"Acid Rain"@en "Chocolate"@en}
  ?en rdfs:label ?label .
  optional { ?en owl:sameAs ?es . FILTER regex(str(?es), "es.dbpedia") }
  filter not exists {?en a skos:Concept}
}
```

returns

```
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["label", "en", "es"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "en", "value": "Chocolate" }    , "en": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chocolate" } , "es": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Chocolate" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "en", "value": "Acid Rain" }    , "en": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Acid_Rain" }} ] } }
```

Note the absence of Spanish results for `"Acid Rain"`. However, the `owl:sameAs` section of http://dbpedia.org/page/Acid_rain clearly has results for Spanish, and it starts with `http://es.dbpedia`.

**Why does the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint not return the `owl:sameAs` results when they are clearly listed on DBpedia?**

Comment: I have some limited success using `(owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)+`. It definitely pulls up the Spanish equivalent for Acid_Rain. However, if I try to grab multiple languages at once - like `optional { ?en (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)+ ?es . FILTER regex(str(?es), "es.dbpedia") }
  optional { ?en (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)+ ?pt . FILTER regex(str(?pt), "pt.dbpedia") }` - I get this error: `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable '_::trans_subj_6_2' is used in subexpressions of the query but not assigned`

Comment: It's a bug in Virtuoso then. You could/should open a ticket on their Github repository or post it on their mailing list such that it can be fixed.

Comment: @AKSW , do you mean the `(owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)+` predicate is a bug or the lack of results for `dbr:Acid_Rain` using plain `owl:sameAs` is a bug?

Comment: I mean the error that occurs when you use multiple `Optional` patterns. For a single `optional` pattern it works with the property path `(owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)+` construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the multiple optionals should have worked. Perhaps an issue in Virtuoso as suggested by @ASKW in the comments?

You should be able to get the different languages in a single regex statement, e.g.:

```
FILTER regex(str(?es), "(es|pt).dbpedia") }
```

Just in case you are looking for Spanish and other language versions of the labels, there is an easier way to do this.  If so try the following:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
   VALUES ?label {"Acid Rain"@en "Chocolate"@en}
   ?en rdfs:label ?label .
   ?en rdfs:label ?allLabels .
   FILTER (lang(?allLabels) = "es")
}
```

Be aware that `OPTIONAL` can be expensive because it effectively increases the search space.  So avoid unless necessary, and in your case optional is not required.

Another solution, BTW, is to filter using CONTAINS().

Comment: That's a neat trick with the labels! I actually just need the DBpedia URIs, though. We have some international users, and I'm coding a utility that will pull the correct DBpedia link to be automatically displayed to them.

Comment: Can you explain why doing the regex this way would work when separate filters wouldn't? I'd like to understand how it works, especially if I'm going to write code to deal with de-normalizing the data.

Comment: I think the multiple optionals should have worked.  Perhaps an issue in Virtuoso?  Optionals can be expensive because they effectively increase the search space, so avoid them unless necessary, and in your case optional is not required.  Another solution, BTW is to filter using `CONTAINS()`.

Comment: Ah, well. If you can put that in your post, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you think this is a Virtuoso-specific issue, best to pursue through Virtuoso-specific resources -- the public [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)